# IOS Location Awareness Programming

Tags: ios, localization, geolocation

Can I send the user location to the server even if the app has exit ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

You can use background location

1. significant location change (iPhone 3Gs and iPhone 4)
2. region monitoring (iPhone 4 only)
3. continuous location change (iPhone 4 only)

Any of the above will work, but you should probably avoid (3) because it will then be making very frequent requests to the same. That'll just kill your battery.

You can try to use TaskCompletion API to send information to server because app is still in background state.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is not running, of course you can't send anything.

Comment: This wakes up my app.No? Applications can register for significant location changes. (Recommended)

Comment: In this case your app is hasn't exited, it's in the background.

Comment: But if it exits it will wake up my app if a significant location change happens.No?

Comment: No, it won't restart your app if it has exited. It will only wake your app up if it is in the background.

Comment: iOS 4 allows sending of some data from a background location process. The app won't open, but it can do some processing and sending.